# Pantheon files sort by accessed

Tags: pantheon-files

Is it possible to sort files in Pantheon according to when they were last accessed? I used to be able to do it in Nautilus when I was running Ubuntu and even show the access time under the file's title. It's especially handy when keeping track of which series episodes I've watched.

Comment: I think the answer is no, but why is it flagged to close? Installing Nautilus for a purpose like this is a good idea. It has no conflicts in eOS.

Comment: I agree. Technically it wouldn't answer the question though would be a useful answer. Do you have reliable installation instructions for Nautilus you could post?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of outstanding wishlist bug reports requesting the ability to show and sort by columns other than those currently provided in List View.  Limited developer resources means this may be not addressed for a while.